.NET 8 Core WPF: DragMove() work only on TextBox not on Border
I have simple WPF window with custom TitleBar but DragMove() works only on TextBlock. If I try to drag window on blank space next to title nothing happens...
<Window x:Class="WPFApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFApplication" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="#FFFFFFFF"
        Title="WPF Application" Height="460" Width="1040">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Custom Title Bar -->
        <Border Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                x:Name="TitleBar" 
                Panel.ZIndex="1">
            <DockPanel>
                <!-- App Name and Icon bar -->
                <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="WPF Application" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="16"/>
                </StackPanel>
                
                <!-- Window Control Buttons -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <!-- Minimize Button -->
                    <Button Width="40"
                            Content="_"
                            Click="MinimizeWindow"
                            Background="Transparent"/>
                    <!-- Maximize/Restore Button -->
                    <Button Width="40"
                            Content="▢" 
                            Click="MaximizeRestoreWindow" 
                            Background="Transparent"/>
                    <!-- Close Button -->
                    <Button Width="40" 
                            Content="X"
                            Click="CloseWindow" 
                            Background="Transparent"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Text="test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           TitleBar.MouseDown += (sender, e) =>
           {
               if (e.ButtonState == System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Pressed)
               {
                   // Call DragMove only if left mouse button is down
                   this.DragMove();
               }
           };
       }

       private void MinimizeWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
       }

       private void MaximizeRestoreWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
               this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
           else
               this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
       }

       private void CloseWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           this.Close();
       }
   }


Try using PreviewMouseDown event? Or maybe you just need to <Border Background="Transparent" ... />.

Thanks @Sinatr !! By setting Background property on Border element worked. For the next Google searches, now I have this and it's working
<Border Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Background="{StaticResource ColorPrimary500}"
        x:Name="TitleBar" 
        Panel.ZIndex="1">

